# How can I add Windows DateTimePicker to a win32 Application in c++

Tags: .net, c++, winapi

I have a Win32 application and i want to Add a DateTimePicker Control, like the one in .NET. I though don't want to include the whole Framework in my application, nor MFC or whatever.

How can I add the native control in a Way with the least amount of dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761815(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Its much simpler than i thought! After adding a Date-Time-Control to the dialog ressource in the Visual Stuoresource Editor, all you have to do is calling Sending Messages DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME and DTM_GETSYSTEMTIME to set the initial and get the modified value. No additional Code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679(VS.85).aspx) and "SysDateTimePick32" as the class name.

Answer (score 1):

See the MSDN documentation for [Using Date and Time Picker Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761815(VS.85).aspx)

EDIT: Ignore my previous reply, there actually is a Win32 class for this.